# Как записать в файл определенное количество чисел, например по 5 чисел в строке?

Tags: c++

Всем привет.
Хотел узнать, как записать в файл определенное количество чисел, например по 5 чисел в строке? Допустим массив чисел записываем в файл.

Например

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

или

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12
```

Вот, собственно пример без перехода по 5 числам.

```
mas[0]=1;
mas[1]=2;
mas[2]=3;
//...
mas[7]=8
ofstream out ("1.txt", ios::app);
for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
{
 out << mas[i] << endl;
}
out.close();
```

**Вопрос закрыт!)**

Comment: Пройти циклом по массиву символов, каждый символ дописывать в строку через пробел.

Comment: да это понятно. Мне надо 5 чисел в строке, потом уже переход на новую строку.

Comment: Переведите последний комментарий на русский язык.

1. Если число (2 символа) не влезает в 5 символов (уже занято 4), что делать?
2. Если символы многобайтные, как их считать?

Comment: correct: символ - это число. Извините за некорректность вопроса

Comment: @marioxxx

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <=n; i++)
    {
       out << mas[i];
       if((i+1) % 5 == 0) cout << endl;
    }
    if (i % 5) cout << endl;

Вроде так. Проверка после цикла -- чтобы не было двух переводов строки.

Comment: excellent! Поправка вместо cout использовать out

Comment: C#/Linq:

    var numbers = new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    File.WriteAllText(filename, string.Join("",
        Enumerable.Range(1, numbers.Length)
                  .Select(i => i % 5 == 0 ? Environment.NewLine : " ")
                  .Zip(numbers, (sep, n) => n.ToString() + sep)));

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ofstream out;

  int data[15] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}; // данные для записи в файл

  out.open("data_out.txt");
  if (!out.is_open())
  {
    cout << "Error opening file data_out.txt.\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (int idx = 0; idx < 15; idx++)
  {
    if (idx && !(idx%5))
      out << endl;

    out << data[idx] << " ";
  }

  out.close();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Э.. а мож кто объяснит, за что минусанули товарища?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
кому минус поставили? 
+1 к alexnewman))

Answer (score 2):

для windows:

```
   #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream out;

    out.open("C:\\123.txt", ios::out);

    if (!out)
        throw("file not open");

    const int ARRAYSIZE = 15;

    int arr[ARRAYSIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    string s;
    char buf[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
        if (((i + 1) % 5) == 0){
            itoa(arr[i], buf, 10); // переводим число в строку для msvs
            s += buf;
            s += "\n";
            out << s.c_str();
            s.clear();
        }   else {
            itoa(arr[i], buf, 10); // переводим число в строку для msvs
            s += buf;
            s += " ";
        }
    }

    if ((ARRAYSIZE % 5) != 0) // добавлено для размера массива не кратному пяти элементов
  out << s.c_str();

    out.close();
}
```

---

123.txt

---

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

***_******_***____исправлено по совету [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream out;

    out.open("C:\\123.txt", ios::out);

    if (!out)
        throw("file not open");

const int ARRAYSIZE = 14;

    int arr[ARRAYSIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
    string s;
    char buf[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
        itoa(arr[i], buf, 10);
        out << buf << " ";
        if (((i + 1) % 4) == 0){
            out << "\n";
        }
    }

    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но alexlz уже ответил) +1)

Comment: @perfect, а для 14 чисел, что должно быть?

У Вас вообще вывод последней строки выполняется **только!!!**, если количество чисел кратно 5.

Ошибочка-с.


Про неоптимальность опкраций с **string s** я вообще уже говорить не хочу.

Comment: @avp поправил код. а почему применять конкатенацию строк неправильно?

Comment: Конкатенацию строк делать не то, чтобы неправильно, а просто ни к чему (неэффективно это).

В этой задаче надо сразу выводить данные (как в ответе @alexnewman или комментарии @alexlz).

Comment: попробовал сразу данные загонять в файл. работает... спасибо за совет